# How to edit a ABPersonSetImageData from Address book

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I am working on an iPhone application which works with AddressBook contacts. I am trying to fetch the image from address book and edit then save that image.

But I don't know how to update and save that image. Please give me a solution if anybody knows about this.

Thanx in advance.

Here's the .h file

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblName;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgGet;
UIImage *imgContact;
NSString* name;
```

The .m file

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    name = [(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) autorelease];
    lblName.text = name;
    if(ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
        imgContact = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
        imgGet.image = imgContact;
        CFRelease(imageData);
    } else {
        imgGet.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ABPicturePerson@2x.png"];
    }

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:(YES) completion:nil];

return NO;
}
```

Here After fetching image and name from above method then i open gallery and select an image then click on below method button but image not saved or update in address book

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveClicked {
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgGet.image);
    CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
 ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
    CFErrorRef error;

    ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error); // <-- clean any image first from ref
    //ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

    ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);

    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    CFRelease(cfdata);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This link is hint for me that how to update your image..

http://davidbits.blogspot.in/2010/01/iphone-update-addressbook-contact.html

declare 1 object in .h file

```
NSInteger recordID;
```

then open contact list and for fetching the contact we use this method

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController     *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
   recordID  =  ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
    name = [(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) autorelease];
    lblName.text = name;
    if(ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
    CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
    your uiimage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)imageData];
    you uiimageview.image = your uiimage;
    CFRelease(imageData);
   } else {
    you uiimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ABPicturePerson@2x.png"];
   }

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:(YES) completion:nil];
    //[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
}
```

then write action for save detail or update detail

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveClicked
{
CFErrorRef *aberror = NULL;    
ABRecordRef aRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recordID);
if (aRecord) {
    NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(your uiimage);
    ABPersonSetImageData(aRecord, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
}
ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, aberror);
//BOOL didAdd = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil);
CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

sure you will get result..

Answer (score 2):

Use `ABRecordRef person` when you want to update:

Firstly `create` `ABAddressBookRef`:

```
// Request authorization to Address Book
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
```

Now `check` `person` has `image`:

```
if(ABPersonHasImageData(person)) 
{
   //remove image as we want to update to new image
   NSError *anError;
   if(ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &anError))
      NSLog(@"removed");
   else
      NSLog(@"%@",[anError description]);
}
```

`Update`

```
 UIImage *image = image here;
 NSData *picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f);
 ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)picData, nil);
```

call `saving function`:

```
 ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, nil);
```